# Adding image programmatically in view

Tags: objective-c, view, sdk

I added image in my view programmatically. But my app has aborted when I switch to view where added image with code

```
UIImageView *countryFlag = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:CountryFlagImage]];
[countryFlag setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:countryFlag];
[countryFlag release];
countryFlag = nil;
```

In - (id)initWithNibName I have

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil CountryFlagImage:(NSString*)imageFlagName
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) { 
         CountryFlagImage = [NSString stringWithString:imageFlagName];
    }
    return self;
}
```

CountryFlagImage I took from previous main view.

Comment: is CountryFalgImage a property? I find a bit suspect the stringWithString: line. Better I don't understand what you want to get doing that...

Comment: Is CountryFlagImage an instance variable declared in your header file?

Comment: What does your stack trace say?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a retain problem... try retaining `CountryFlagImage` maybe is being released before you can use it.

Comment: Console shows me
`2011-11-12 19:55:57.226 EuroCountries[4967:207] -[UIImageView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b1b940
2011-11-12 19:55:57.357 EuroCountries[4967:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b1b940'` and `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'` Retaining of `CountryFlagImage` doesn't gave any result.